# VB6 application : WebBrowser.Navigate refresh every 3 minutes

Tags: vb6, timer, browser, browser-refresh

I am making an application using VB6 in which a WebBrowser window is launched using this code:

```
     Private Sub Form_Load()
     WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://google.com")
     End Sub
```

How can I make the window refresh the same url every let's say 3 minutes ?
I know it should be something well known but i am still searching my way through VB programming

Comment: You shouldn't have brackets around the URL unless you're using `Call` or using the return value of `.Navigate`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need 2 timers. just have a global variable `globalTimer As Date` that keeps the last time you navigated
You can set Timer1 to run every second or minute. To be more accurate, I recommend every second.

```
Dim globalTimer As Date
...
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If Now >= DateAdd("n", 3, globalTimer) Then    ' its been at least 3 minutes since last Navigation
        WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://google.com") ' Navigate
        globalTimer = Now                          ' store the new navigation time
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried the code, it refreshes the browser every 3 seconds, but it does not open the website google as it used to be with the previous code, any help please !

Comment: WOOOPS! Big time mistake on my part... `If globalTimer >= DateAdd("n", 3, Now) Then` should be `If Now >= DateAdd("n", 3, globalTimer) Then`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer to run code at a regular interval.
As the VB6 timer has a maximum interval of ~65s, you can set it to a 60,000ms interval, and keep a separate counter and when it gets to 3, reset it back to 0 and perform a refresh.

```
Private Sub Timer_Timer
  'Increment minute count
  FireCount = FireCount + 1

  If FireCount = 3 then
    'Reset to 0 for next time
    FireCount = 0

    'Refresh web browser
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you please tell where i can find resources / tutorials on how to make this since i am null at VB6

Comment: @NizarBark It's a simple timer, an increment and if statement, there is nothing to tutor.

Comment: I have put the following code  `code`Private Sub Form_Load()
     WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://www.google.com")
     End Sub

Private Sub T_Timer()

  'Increment minute count
  FireCount = FireCount + 1

  If FireCount = 3 Then
    'Reset to 0 for next time
    FireCount = 0
WebBrowser1.Refresh ("http://www.google.com")
    'Refresh web browser
  End If
End Sub`code` but it give me an alert saying compile error : wrong number or argument or invalid property assignment

Comment: @NizarBark Well, where did you get the `WebBrowser1.Refresh ("google.com")` line from? that's not the code you had in your question. As the compiler error said, `.Refresh` doesn't have that many parameters.